# Cannot cast from View to Button?

Tags: java, android, xml

Recently I have been attempting to develop an android app, but I hit large roadblock very early on. I am getting the error "Cannot cast from View to Button" on the line `Button lost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lost1);` Here is the xml for that part

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/lost1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/lost"
        android:textColor="@color/lostfoundtext"
        android:textColorLink="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />`
```

Comment: Are you using fragments or activities?  If it is an activity don't forget to setContentView, and if it is in a fragment, don't forget to expand the xml to the right one.  It may not be finding the correct lost1, or it may be trying to get a different view with the same name in another layout.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I did set the content view, and its not a fragment/ Can you elaborate upon expanding the xml? Thanks!

Comment: If it is a fragment then you have to set the xml layout you want to expand.  That is basically what the activity takes care of when you setContentView.  If it is expanding, make sure no other element has the same ID otherwise it may be finding that one first and then failing to cast the other view as a button.

Comment: check that in your contentview has another lost1 id

Comment: That's one big button!  Worked fine for me.  As other's have said, make sure you don't have any other elements with `android:id="@+id/lost1"`.  It's probably a copy/paste error.

Comment: Also make sure (this is a long shot) that you don't have your own class named Button.